# Conditional Gaussian confusion

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Suppose
$$z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I) $$
$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Gamma) $$
and
$$x=\mu + A\cdot z +\epsilon$$

I understand that the $x$ given $z$ is distributed
$$x|z\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu + A\cdot z,\Gamma)$$
because when we are conditioning on $z$, we are to treat it like a constant (it is not a random variable,  as it is "given").

My question concerns calculating the distribution of $z|x$. We have
$$x=\mu + A\cdot z +\epsilon$$
$$\implies$$
$$A^{-1}\cdot(x-\mu-\epsilon)=z$$
But if I proceed as above,I get a wrong result...
$$z=A^{-1}\cdot x -A^{-1}\cdot\mu -A^{-1}\cdot\epsilon$$
$$E(z|x)=E(A^{-1}\cdot x) -E(A^{-1}\cdot\mu) - E(A^{-1}\cdot\epsilon)$$
$$E(z|x)=A^{-1}\cdot x -A^{-1}\cdot\mu - 0$$
$$E(z|x)=A^{-1}\cdot (x-\mu) $$

Which is wrong, as the text I am reading states:
$$E(z|x)=A^t(AA^t+\Gamma)^{-1}(x-\mu)$$

Where am I making a mistake? How can I derive the correct result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good question. Your finding is related to the regression dilution phenomenon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_dilution

In the beginning, it is implicitly assumed that $z$ and $\epsilon$ are independent Gaussian deviates. This means $x$ and $\epsilon$ are correlated. You cannot have both $x$ and $z$ being independent with $\epsilon$. Therefore, even if you write $z=A^{-1} (x-\mu-\epsilon)$, it does not follow that the expectation value of $z$ given $x$ is $A^{-1}(x-\mu)$, because the correlation between $x$ and $\epsilon$ means that the expectation value of $\epsilon$ given $x$ is no longer $0$. You can read about regression dilution to deepen your understanding of this.

Comment: The text does state that $\epsilon$ and $z$ are independent. I see, so the mistake I had made is that I assumed $E(\epsilon|x)=0$?

Comment: That's right. Since they are correlated.